# Save Site as Template Programatically - Error generating solution files in temporary directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sitetemplate

I have a requirement like , i need to create the Site Templates programatically.
when i am trying to save the Site As Template Programatically , i am getting the below error.
**"Error generating solution files in temporary directory"**.
i have given full control on c:\windows\temp directory.And I am using below Method:

```
oWeb.SaveAsTemplate(templateName, templateTitle, tmplDesc, true);
```

(or)

```
string solutionFileUrl = SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(oWeb,templateName, templateTitle,tmplDesc,SPSolutionExporter.ExportMode.FullReuse,true);
```

facing the same issue.

i am able to save root web as Template like SPContext.Current.Web.SaveAsTemplate(templateName, templateTitle, tmplDesc, true);
but i need to save sub site as Template.

Below is my ULS log dump

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist.  The
>   page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have
>   been deleted by another
>   user.0x81020026,
>   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId,
>   String strListName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.ItemByInternalName(Guid webId,
>   String listName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.EnsureList()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.EnsureListAndView(Boolean
>   requireFullBlownViewSchema)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.ShouldSerializeTitle()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterListViewWebPart.Write14_ListViewWebPart...
>   ...(String n, String ns, ListViewWebPart o, Boolean isNullable,
>   Boolean needType)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterListViewWebPart.Write15_WebPart(Object
>   o)     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeWriter(XmlMapping
>   mapping, XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces
>   namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)     at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.S... ...erialize(XmlWriter
>   xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String
>   encodingStyle, String id)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.SerializeXml(XmlWriter
>   writer, XmlSerializer xmls, Boolean shouldSerializeAll)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.SerializeWebPartXml(Boolean
>   shouldExcludeSpecialProperties, TextWriter writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.WriteXmlAsUtf8(Boolean
>   shouldExcludeSpecialProperties)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.GetWebPartXml(WebPart
>   webPart, Boolean shouldUTF8Encode, Boolean
>   shouldExcludeSpecialProperties, Boolean export)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart(WebPart
>   webPart, XmlWriter writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter...
>   ....GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder,
>   List`1 webViews)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder
>   folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder
>   folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInWeb(String
>   workflowTemplateName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GenerateSolutionFiles()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web,
>   String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode
>   exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName,
>   String destina... ...tionListUrl, Action`1 solutionPostProcessor,
>   Boolean activateSolution)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.SaveAsTemplate(String strTemplateName,
>   String strTemplateTitle, String strTemplateDescription, Boolean
>   fSaveData)     at
>   TemplateIssueProject.ProjectTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__6()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   TemplateIssueProject.ProjectTemplate.SaveTemplate(String webName,
>   String templateName, String template... ...Title, String tmplDesc)
>   at TemplateIssueProject.ProjectTemplate.SiteCreation(String siteName) 
>   at
>   TemplateIssueProject.TemplateIssewebpart.TemplateIssewebpart.btnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   ASP.WKPSTD_ASPX__1961116010.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecut...
>   ...ionStep.Execute()     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletio...
>   ...n(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
>   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder
>   folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder
>   folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder
>   folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInWeb(String
>   workflowTemplateName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GenerateSolutionFiles()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution()
>
> Application error when access /SitePages/MyTaskPage.aspx, Error=Error
>   generating solution files in temporary directory.   at
>   TemplateIssueProject.ProjectTemplate.SiteCreation(String siteName)
>   at
>   TemplateIssueProject.TemplateIssewebpart.TemplateIssewebpart.btnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Error generating solution files in
>   temporary directory.    at
>   TemplateIssueProject.ProjectTemplate.SiteCreation(String siteName)
>   at
>   TemplateIssueProject.TemplateIssewebpart.TemplateIssewebpart.btnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Please suggest/provide suggestions.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code is used to save the site as Template(Root Level/subsite)

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
Add Reference to your solution from the below path.

Reference Path: C:\Windows\winsxs\msil_system.management.automation_31bf3856ad364e35_7.1.7601.18071_none_a682d4c5c360dacf\System.Management.Automation.dll

RunspaceInvoke oRunSpaceInvoke = new RunspaceInvoke();
                    FullWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/" + objTemplate.strWebName;
                    strScriptToSaveTemp = @"Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell ; Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ;" +
                                    "$oWeb = Get-SPWeb " + FullWebUrl + " ; $oWeb.SaveAsTemplate('" + objTemplate.strTemplateTitle + "','" + objTemplate.strTemplateName + "','" + objTemplate.strTemplateDesc + "',1) \n";
oRunSpaceInvoke.Invoke(strScriptToSaveTemp).ToString();
```

Regards,
Mahesh
http://sharepointchampion.blogspot.in/2014/05/save-site-as-template-programatically.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have added any fields through a feature, and your field has Overwrite="FALSE", then site exporting will fail. You should only use Overwrite if you need to set it to TRUE, since the default is FALSE.

This seems to be a SharePoint bug.

You may see this attribute mentioned in your ULS logs.